# Fatal error when replacing fuction output with a string using plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I'm, learning magento development and trying to create a custom module in Magento 2.3.6 with page at **localhost/magento236/lesson3/Page/view**

The template file at **Lesson3/Module/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml** calls ViewModel function to output a friend's name from database

```
<?php
$viewModel = $this->getData('view_model');
$viewModel2 = $block->getViewModel();
echo ($viewModel->getFriendName(1));
?>
```

ViewModel is located at **Lesson3/Module/ViewModel/Lesson3ViewModel.php**
Part of ViewModel with function to change looks like this

```
   public function getFriendName($id)
    {
        return $this->getFriendModel($id)->getData('name');
    }
```

It works fine, shows a name from database with specified ID.

I need to output instead of friend's name any string. So I try to do this with magento plugin interceptor.

Created **di.xml** at **Lesson3/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Lesson3\Module\ViewModel\Lesson3ViewModel">
        <plugin name="Lesson3_Module" type="Lesson3\Module\Model\Plugin"
     sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Created plugin class at **Lesson3/Module/Model/Plugin.php**

```
<?php   
namespace Lesson3\Module\Model;
class Plugin
{
    public function aftergetFriendName(
        Lesson3\Module\ViewModel\Lesson3ViewModel $product, $name
    ) {
        $name = "TEXT";
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Executed **php bin/magento set:di:compile**, ran **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** anf flushed cache **php bin/magento cache:flush**.

When accessing the page there is **Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Lesson3\Module\Model\Plugin::aftergetFriendName() must be an instance of Lesson3\Module\Model\Lesson3\Module\ViewModel\Lesson3ViewModel**

Please specify to me what should I have done to make it work

Comment: After run php bin/magento set:di:compile run command,
If's there is something permission issue like you do 777 permission on the generated folder then check, I hope it's working!

Comment: I have reset Magento and now I'm getting Fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Should be

```
 public function aftergetFriendName(
        \Lesson3\Module\ViewModel\Lesson3ViewModel $product, $name
    )
```

not

```
 public function aftergetFriendName(
        Lesson3\Module\ViewModel\Lesson3ViewModel $product, $name
    )
```